# Automotive connector type

Tags: connector, identification, automotive

Does anyone know what kind of connector this is? It is used in a battery pack of a car for Can bus, k-line and power.

Dimensions: 12mm x 10mm x 6.5mm

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit: this is a similar 12-pin female connector (on the right):

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us with an idea of scale here?

Comment: Those cable look like 14/010 so the plug may be 10mm by 15mm by 20mm but wag...

Comment: Automotive connectors are kind of a world of their own (though you can buy some nice sealed sensor connectors through electronic distribution channels now), so you might want to check the car repair SE, particularly if you just looking for onesy-twosies.

Answer (score 1):

This is the connector:

```
JST 08CPT-B-2A - Wire-To-Board Connector, 2 mm, 8 Contacts, Receptacle, CPT Series, 2 Rows
```